# How to delete strings following a character which appears more than one time?

Tags: python, sas

I have a paragraph:
Governmental Authority means any nation or government. The term would be explained further. Guaranty Obligations means as to any Person (without duplication) any obligation. Intellectual Property Rights means all actual or prospective rights arising in connection with any intellectual property.

In this paragraph, ***means*** appears three times. I would like to delete all strings after the second occurrence of means. In the above case, the result I want is:
Governmental Authority means any nation or government. The term would be explained further. Guaranty Obligations

Could I ask how to achieve that via SAS?

Or Python is also Okay, but the problem is that now I have a table containing two columns. The first column is the firmname, and the other is the paragraph which includes the paragraph just like the above. I have many observations. How could I generate a new column which shows the strings before the second ***means***?

Comment: This is not a code writing service - have a go at it yourself and then ask for help with specific issues that are stopping you from progressing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FINDW()` in SAS. The fourth parameter in the FINDW is where to start searching, so search twice. 
Do a single search to find the first term. 
Do a second search to find the second term.

You may want to look at the options for the modifiers, especially if your data is not all the same case. There are options for ignoring case, or you can use `UPCASE()` to make everything upper case.

```
data have;
    length text want $5000;
    search_term='means';
    text="Governmental Authority means any nation or government. The term would be explained further. Guaranty Obligations means as to any Person (without duplication) any obligation. Intellectual Property Rights means all actual or prospective rights arising in connection with any intellectual property.";
    first_mean=findw(text, search_term);
    second_mean=findw(text, search_term, ' ', first_mean+5);
    want=substr(text, 1, second_mean-2);
run;

proc print;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
text = """Governmental Authority means any nation or government. 
The term would be explained further. Guaranty Obligations means as to any 
Person (without duplication) any obligation. Intellectual Property Rights 
means all actual or prospective rights arising in connection with 
any intellectual property."""

means_indexes = [ix for ix, i in enumerate(text.split()) if i == 'means']
txt = ''
if len(means_indexes) > 1: txt = ' '.join(text.split()[0:temp[1]])
else: txt = text

print(txt)
```

> 'Governmental Authority means any nation or government. The term would
>   be explained further. Guaranty Obligations'

Comment: Yes, it works. However, how it works in a Table where text here is just a column?

Comment: You mean you have a column that contains multiple text segments?

Comment: I mean I have a table with many rows and two columns. One column is called Paragraph, which includes the paragraph.

Comment: Iterate through that column and apply the above function iteratively.

Comment: Could I ask how to code the iteration please? Many Thanks!

Comment: What kind of data structure is your table saved as?